# VLC does not play any video or mp3 file, closes when a file is opened

Tags: 12.04, vlc

When I run vlc from terminal I get:

*In the VLC dialog box:*

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/Ent/movies/the%20mask.avi'. Check the log for details.
```

*In terminal:*

```
VLC media player 2.0.1 Twoflower (revision 2.0.1-0-gf432547)
[0x8fe8f8] main input error: open of `file/xspf-open:///home/para/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' failed
[0x8fe8f8] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0x8fe8f8] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file/xspf-open:///home/para/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'. Check the log for details.
[0x8f1aa8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8f9b08] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8be008] main libvlc error: option http-user-agent does not exist
[0x8be008] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x8f9b08] qt4 interface error: Unable to load extensions module
[0x7f5280000b78] main input error: open of `file:///media/Ent/movies/the%20mask.avi' failed
[0x8fc718] main playlist error: could not export playlist
```

This happens for every file i run with vlc. Need help in troubleshooting the problem in vlc , this started when i installed vlc 1.0* by mistake when 2.0.1 was already there so i removed vlc from synaptic package manager and reinstalled it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do several things here; this is what I did when I had a similar problem (see the three commands below). I removed `vlc` and all its configuration files by running the *first* command; with the *second* I removed all the extra items it installs, and with the *third* I cleaned the apt `cache` so the package needs to be downloaded again; i.e. `/var/cache/apt/archives` is cleared.

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

As has been suggested, it is also important to remove any traces of the program from your home folder, as the purge procedure does not remove them, so remove the following folders as well (use `-i` instead of `-f` if you want to confirm removal). It is alright to remove the `vlc` folders here  and not just the contents of the folder, as the folders will be reconstituted when you reinstall `vlc`.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/vlc
rm -rf ~/.config/vlc
rm -rf ~/.local/share/vlc
```

That should help eliminate the problems you encountered with the configuration of vlc; it is particularly **important** to remove the `vlc` folder in `.config` as that contains the file `vlc-qt-interface.conf`, which you mentioned appeared in the error logs and seems to be preventing `vlc` from opening.

Now you should be able to run

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This should sort out the problem, but we can look into other possibilities if necessary and if you provide further information.

Answer (score 1):

Run this to clean your vlc settings, then try running vlc again

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/vlc/
```