# VLC unable to open any files

Tags: sound, video, vlc, crash

What has happened to VLC. I think it updated when the kernel did recently and now it can't open anything:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL
```

The terminal gives:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0xfb4f68] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xfb4f68] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xfcfe08] main input error: open of `file/xspf-open:///home/shaun/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' failed
[0xfcfe08] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0xfcfe08] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file/xspf-open:///home/shaun/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'. Check the log for details.
[0xfd1f98] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xfa1118] main libvlc error: interface "hotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0xfdc958] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xfa1118] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0xfa1118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0xfdc9c8] qt4 interface error: Unable to load extensions module
[0x7f9e0c001958] main input error: open of `file:///media/storage/Downloads/Music/tone.m4a' failed
```

I've tried the usual uninstall of vlc aka `sudo apt-get remove vlc --purge`. And when I reinstall it still fails. I've also just added their ppa from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version).

I've run out of ideas. Anything I haven't tried?

Comment: Have you tried removing `/home/shaun/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf`?

Comment: Ok I reinstalled it and now it gives:
```
...
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
[0xd95438] main playlist error: could not export playlist
```
and it is unresponsive

Comment: That last bit of the error mentioning the playlist suggests there's something wrong with that file I mentioned previously and/or other files that may not have been removed after reinstalling. Follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/179910/198486) to completly remove files that may be causing this problem Although probably just running `rm -rf ~/.local/share/vlc/` may fix it.

Comment: None of that works. Same error message

Comment: Ok, Well after changing nothing the "invalid Pixmap" error has disappeared leaving only the read "unable to open" error